# Exim4 configuration check exist alias or in mysql table

Tags: mail-server, exim, exim4

What is the wrong inside this condition its not working.
 `${if or {${eq {${lookup mysql{SELECT 1 FROM logs WHERE email='${quote_mysql:$local_part@$domain}'}{1}}}{1}}} {${eq {${lookup{$local_part}lsearch{/etc/aliases}{1}}}{1}}}}`